# Discord Bot doesnt recognize commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

I tried to code a Discord Bot but I cant even get the commands to work.
Used replit.com as the IDE and to run the bot.

This is the main.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music

cogs = [music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents = discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
  cogs[i].setup(client)


client.run("token")
```

And this is the code for the bot:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self,ctx):
      if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("join channel")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
          await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
          await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self,ctx):
      await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
      ctx.voice_client.stop()
      FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
      YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
      vc = ctx.voice_client

      with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        vc.play(source)

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self,ctx):
      await ctx.voice_client.pause()
      await ctx.send("pause")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self,ctx):
      await ctx.voice_client.resume()
      await ctx.send("resume")

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self,ctx):
      await ctx.send("test!")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

It runs without error but if i try to use ?test or any other command it gives me this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "test" is not found
```

Ive seen that other users had the same problem but I couldnt find a fix for it.

I only have basic experience with Python and none with Discord bots, so its probably some stupid error I made.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is `test` being defined in `music` or `__init__`? If it's the latter, it should be the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TheFungusAmongUs pointed out, your indentation is off. Your test function, and all others under the `music` class for that matter, should be on the same indentation level as `__init__()`.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self,ctx):
      if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("join channel")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
          await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
          await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self,ctx):
      await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
      ctx.voice_client.stop()
      FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
      YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
      vc = ctx.voice_client

      with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        vc.play(source)

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self,ctx):
      await ctx.voice_client.pause()
      await ctx.send("pause")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self,ctx):
      await ctx.voice_client.resume()
      await ctx.send("resume")

    @commands.command()
    async def test(self,ctx):
      await ctx.send("test!")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```